# How to display array in String as table rows with Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, arrays

In my script I'm getting a String as a result from PHP database request through an ajax call. The result string looks like this:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "181"
    ["number"]=>
    string(2) "37"
    ["livingid"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "181"
    ["number"]=>
    string(2) "37"
    ["livingid"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "185"
    ["number"]=>
    string(2) "37"
    ["livingid"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "185"
    ["number"]=>
    string(2) "37"
    ["livingid"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }}
```

I dont know why it is returned like this. I want to display the result in a table. For that I would use jquery:

```
   $("#deActWh").append(result); //#deActWh is the id of table
```

But this is only working, if I'm having the html table syntx in the string like `<tr> <td>` and so on. Im looking for a good way to convert this string back to an array and inserting the html syntax in each row. I also need to get rid of all the unnecessary stuff like "array(4)... string(3) ..etc." I thougt about using the split() method, but I dont know how I could use this method usefully here. I'm open for suggestions or other approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning it as a php array, you can return it as a json_encoded string.

I am assuming that you are using pdo to fetch the result out from mysql and you return that straight away to to the ajax.

`$result = whatever your pdo call is.`

`return json_encode($result);`

Since jquery is javascript, it can interpret JSON easily. However, you still have to loop through and build the table yourself.

Comment: Thank you. this already helped a lot. The return string is now in properly JSON format except of a "string(1738)" at the beginning. Do you know whats going on with this ? I would just cut it away with substring or split() and pop().

Comment: it should not have that. can you paste your code here so I can see it? If you have "string" it's most likely you are doing var_dump or something.

Comment: Oh yeah apparantly the php method uses var_dump; and die; statement after. I've tried now to use return statement, but then the ajax call gets nothing back. I'm new to this project and don't understand how everything is implemented. Unfortunatley I can't ask anyone and it's not clear for me what else I could use to get a usable return from php.

Comment: With return statment I'm only becoming an empty array.

Comment: It is working now with an echo statement and die; statement after. But I'm pretty sure this is not a good solution..

Comment: If it's all in one page, then you have no choice but to use echo. `return` statements are usually used in MVC. Where controller would return a json value to the view. echo is fine if it's a script with html codes in it. Not the best way nowadays to create a page like this.

Comment: It is MVC or kind of it actually. It is using backbone.js and handlebars. I am also wondering why return statement doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

#### This problem is arising because of the PHP script

The PHP is deliberately formatting the data like that. It is not Javascript notation, which would have `[` and `]` for arrays and also wouldn't have the format `[0]=>` for the zero'th element of an array.

Check the documentation of the database, which will explain the format of its output.